# How do i find $(1+i)^{100}?$

Tags: complex-numbers

How do I find $(1+i)^{100}$ without expanding $(1+i)$ 100 times?

Is there a quicker way to do this?

The hint was to find the modulus and argument of $1+i$ which I've got as $\sqrt{2}$ and $\pi/4$ but I'm not sure what to do from here.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

$$(1+i)^2=2i\qquad \Longrightarrow\qquad (1+i)^4=-4.$$

Comment: Nice solution, it reduces the calculation directly to integers.

Comment: The simplest solution! Nice!

Comment: No this solution distracts from the whole point of the question

Comment: @JohnFernley Another [barometer problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barometer_question)?

Comment: @JohnFernley Yes, it doesn't do what the question 'asks', but it's delightfully-simple.

Comment: Any difference from $(1+i)=\sqrt{2}e^{\frac{i\pi}{4}}$ in simplicity is very slight

Answer (score 14):

Hint: $$(1+i)=\sqrt{2}e^{\frac{i\pi}{4}}$$

Answer (score 6):

Hint:

$1+i=\sqrt{2} e^{i\pi/4}$

Therefore, $(1+i)^{100}= [\sqrt{2} e^{i\pi/4}]^{100}=\sqrt{2}^{100}e^{i100\pi/4}=[{{2^{0.5}}}]^{100}e^{i(24\pi+\pi)}=2^{50}e^{i\pi}=2^{50}(-1)=\boxed{-2^{50}}$

Your job: how did we get $1+i=\sqrt{2} e^{i\pi/4}$?

To do this kind of problem in general, look at the **polar form** of a complex number:

http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Extras/ComplexPrimer/Forms.aspx

Answer (score 5):

You can use [De Moivre's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula), $1+i=\sqrt{2}(\cos \frac{\pi}{4}+i \sin \frac{\pi}{4})$, so $(1+i)^{100}=(\sqrt{2})^{100}(\cos 25\pi+i \sin 25\pi)$

Answer (score 1):

The ( at least a ) key is that the powers are periodic (argument-wise) .One way of doing Complex multiplication is by doing it geometrically, you multiply two numbers by multiplying their respective moduli and by adding their respective arguments. Notice that $1+i$ lies on the line $y=x$, so that its argument is $\pi/4$. What happens if you go around $\frac {2k\pi}{\pi/4}$ times? The key is that $\pi/4$ is "commensurate" to $2\pi$, meaning it divides exactly (an integer number of times) into $2 \pi$.